# navigator.sendBeacon not called from unload

Tags: onunload, sendbeacon

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) and the specs, navigator.sendBeacon is intended to be called from window unload.
Now, it does not seem to work anymore if you close the last tab of your browser, or your entire browser window.

Can anyone confirm if this is by design? If so, is there a workaround to send lastminute data on unload?

I tested with this sample file, in Firefox 74 and Chrome 81, looking for calls with Fiddler.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>unload test page</title>
<script>
window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
  navigator.sendBeacon('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon');
});
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <p><div>unload test page</div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) states (as of 1/12/2021):

> It’s intended to be used in combination with the visibilitychange
> event (but not with the unload and beforeunload events)

When visibilitychange transitions to *hidden*, you can treat that as when the tab/browser is closing and use sendBeacon then.

Example code from MDN:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function logData() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    navigator.sendBeacon('/log', analyticsData);
  }
});
```

Comment: So with `visibilitychange`, can you `sendBeacon` when closing the last tab of the window? @Casper Since I'm understanding is the point of `visibilitychange` is mostly for mobile.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh Yes, visibilitychange will fire when the tab closes, and sendBeacon can be used at that point.

Comment: The answer is actually NO @Jonathan `visibilitychange` is fired when the user closes a tab, but not when the user closes a window (or closing a tab and that tab is the last one of the window). That's my question.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I just ran some tests and confirmed that visibilitychange IS fired when closing a window or the last tab in Edge and Chrome.

Comment: Fair @Jonathan. My understanding is `visibilitychange` IS fired, but now you can only do sync operation, not async operation like `sendBeacon` because there's no more browser to hold the request of `sendBeacon` alive like in the case of only closing a tab. Is that correct?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh That's mostly correct, yes. sendBeacon will still make the request to the server, but the browser will not hold the request. That is, you can still send analytics to your server (e.g., with sendBeacon), but you will not be able to process any asynchronous responses in the browser.

Comment: for my case I use Firestore to save the analytics data and the request never reached the Firestore server, not sure why. As well, I’m curious what happens if the computer is unexpectedly shut down?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I Have never used Firestore, so I cannot help you there. However, there is nothing you can do in the browser if the user's computer shuts down (or loses internet before closing the page).